# how to convert JSON Data in two JSON array format on basis of type in JPA web API

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jersey, hql

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "holidayId": 1,
      "createdAt": 1334925720000,
      "date": "2012-01-26",
      "description": "Republic Day",
      "holidayType": {
        "holidayTypeId": 1,
        "holidayType": "Normal"
      }
    },
    {
      "holidayId": 11,
      "createdAt": 1334925720000,
      "date": "2012-03-23",
      "description": "Ugadi",
      "holidayType": {
        "holidayTypeId": 2,
        "holidayType": "Normal"
      }
    },
    {
      "holidayId": 21,
      "createdAt": 1334925720000,
      "date": "2012-04-06",
      "description": "Good Friday",
      "holidayType": {
        "holidayTypeId": 1,
        "holidayType": "Normal"
      }
    },
    {
      "holidayId": 31,
      "createdAt": 1334925720000,
      "date": "2012-05-01",
      "description": "May Day",
      "holidayType": {
        "holidayTypeId": 2,
        "holidayType": "Normal"
      }
    },
    }
    ]
    }
```

this is my Current JSON format:

```
public CommonResponseModel getLeaveList() {
        EntityManager entityManager = DBManager.getDBManager();
        List<Holiday> result = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Holiday", Holiday.class).getResultList();

        LeavesResponseWrapper model = new LeavesResponseWrapper();
        model.setData(result);
        DBManager.saveAndClosDB(entityManager);
        return model;
        }
```

this code i am trying to get current JSON data

But i have to get JSON Data in this format desire format:

```
{
 "code": 200,
 "message": "Holiday List",
 "data": {
       "normalHolidays": [
         {
           "name": "Diwali",
           "date": "31-10-2016"
         }
       ],
       "optionalHolidays": [
         {
           "name": "Onam",
           "date": "13-09-2016"
    }
       ]
 }
}
```

please help me how to achieve desire JSON format data we have two table one for holidays and another for Holidays type on the basis of that i am getting that data while i have to get To json array one for TYPE1 another for type2 i am using Jersey jar please help me how to get it .

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of "data" from `List<Holiday>` to `Map<String,List<Holiday>>`.

Then based on holidayType you can separate data in `setData()`.

```
Map<String,List<Holiday>> data;
setData(List<Holiday> holidays) {
    List<Holiday> normalHolidays = new ArrayList<Holiday>();
    List<Holiday> optionalHolidays = new ArrayList<Holiday>();

    for(Holiday holiday : holidays) {
        if("Normal".equals(holiday.holidayType.holidayType)) {
            normalHolidays.add(holiday);
        } else {
            optionalHolidays.add(holiday);
        }
    }

    data = new HashMap<String,List<Holiday>>();
    data.put("normalHolidays", normalHolidays);
    data.put("optionalHolidays", optionalHolidays);
}
```